# Can't find powershell virtual directory when using CodeDeploy

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis, continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy

I have a working deployment script that creates an IIS site and some applications.

I want to add a feature to this script that automatically creates a ssl binding and applied it to the site.

Here is the excerpt

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

#Check if binding exist. If not, create it.
if (!(get-childitem IIS:\SslBindings | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -eq "0.0.0.0" -and $_.port -eq "443"})) {
    cd IIS:\SslBindings
    Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\my | Where-Object -Property Subject -like "*CERTNAME*" | new-item 0.0.0.0!443
}
```

If I run this manually in PSISE, the binding gets created with my cert and applies to site.

But when I Deploy this using codedeploy i get the following error message:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'cert' does not exist.
[stderr]At C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\*************\*-***
[stderr]*****\deployment-archive\createIisSiteWeb.ps1:64 char:13
[stderr]+             Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\my | Where-Object -Prope ...
[stderr]+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[stderr]    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cert:String) [Get-ChildItem], D 
[stderr]   riveNotFoundException
[stderr]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetC 
[stderr]   hildItemCommand
```

This is the same error message you get if the WebAdministration module is not loaded, but it is.

The cert is installed correctly and resides in cert:\localmachine\my

Anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: Are you running the script under a service account? Try logging into the machine once with this account (interactive), after that the certificate store should be created for that specific account so this shouldn't fail after that.